# submitting changes to submodules with EGIt

Tags: github, egit, git-submodules

I just installed EGit 2.3.1 on Eclipse Juno.

I checked out this GitHub project:
https://github.com/erelsgl/machine-learning
which has two submodules - "perceptron" and "classifier".

I made no changes in any of the projects:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
$ git submodule status
 f1002bedc0bbd41866c06d114a299de8a807baf5 classifier (heads/master)
 2a9012c03ea0fb97bd1513a68dd85ba3e6a5f68e perceptron (heads/master)
$ cd perceptron
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

However, when I do "Commit" from Eclipse Git Repositories view, standing on the "perceptron" submodule, I see this:

[image: top]

[image: bottom]

i.e., EGit, for some reason, thinks that I have deleted all files in "perceptron", and added them to the "perceptron/" subfolder!

What am I doing wrong?